# Why formatting date in angular formatted or moment formatted reduce on day from date with time T00:00:00.000Z

Tags: angular, momentjs

I have application which returns dates from database with the following format (2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z)
When I format the date through Angular pipe or moment formatting it reduce one day from date,

for example when I format (2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z) date to get only the date it changes to (2020-07-11)
any solution how can I get the date without reduced day.

```
     moment(2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Because in your local time it *is* the day before.

Comment: What is the solution ?

Comment: The ugly solution, assuming those date values from db are actual strings and not date objects, and if I understand correctly you only care about the day, you can slice the string like this:
`moment(date.slice(0, -14)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: I have the same issue. You need to set the timezone, you will get the exact date.

Comment: Hi @nir Shabi your solution was great if you post it as answer I would accept it, because it helped solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ugly solution, assuming those date values from db are actual strings and not date objects, and if I understand correctly you only care about the day, you can slice the string like this:

```
moment(date.slice(0, -14)).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 1):

Moment retains the UTC offset if you pass it like in your example (Z = Zulu time = UTC+0)

It seems like your local timezone has a negative UTC offset e.g. UTC-1 which would mean in your example that the date on your timezone is actually the day before than in Zulu time.

You can confirm this by printing an ISO 8601 date string from your moment object:

```
moment('2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z').toISOString();
// -> "2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z"

moment('2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z').toISOString(true);
// -> local time e.g. "2020-07-12T03:00:00.000+03:00"
// if your UTC offset is +3

moment('2020-07-12T00:00:00.000Z').toISOString(true);
// -> local time e.g. "2020-07-11T23:00:00.000-01:00"
// if your UTC offset is -1
```